Natural isomorphism involving the Yoneda lemma and Ab-enrichment
Let $\mathbf{Ab}$ be the category of Abelian group and let $\mathbf{C}$ be a small category. I'm interested in the functor category $[\mathbf{C}, \mathbf{Ab}]$, which is an abelian category; in particular each hom-set $[\mathbf{C}, \mathbf{Ab}](\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B})$ has the structure of an abelian group. I will denote by $F \dashv U$ the free-forgetful adjunction between $\mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathbf{Ab}$. Observe that this lifts to an adjunction $F\circ- \dashv U\circ -$ between $[\mathbf{C}, \mathbf{Set}]$ and $[\mathbf{C}, \mathbf{Ab}]$. I will also denote by $y^c : \mathbf{C}^{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ the functor $\mathbf{C}(-,c)$. Now let $A$ be an abelian group and consider the functor $\mathcal{C}_{c,A}$, for short $\mathcal{C}$, given by $ \mathbf{Ab}(Fy^c-,A)$.
I would like to prove that there is a natural isomorphism $[\mathbf{C}, \mathbf{Ab}](\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{C}) \simeq \mathbf{Ab}(\mathcal{A}c, A)$ for all $\mathcal{A} \in [\mathbf{C}, \mathbf{Ab}]$. This should be some consequence of the Yoneda lemma, but I'm not able to see it.
Forgetting about the abelian structure on the hom-sets we have:
$$U\mathbf{Ab}(\mathcal{A}c, A) \simeq [\mathbf{C}^{op}, \mathbf{Set}](y^c, U\mathbf{Ab}(\mathcal{A}-,A)) \simeq [\mathbf{C}^{op}, \mathbf{Ab}](Fy^c, \mathbf{Ab}(\mathcal{A}-,A))$$
but I'm not able to get rid of $op$ nor to swap $\mathcal{A}$ and $Fy^c$.
Any help is appreciated.

Let me please change the notation. Let $F : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ be the left adjoint to the forgetful functor $U  : \mathbf{Ab} \to \mathbf{Set}$. Let $A$ be an abelian group. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category, and let $X \in \mathcal{C}$ be an object.
Your question is about the functor
$$F_{X,A} := \hom(-,A) \circ (F \circ \hom(-,X))^{op} : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Ab},$$
which we can simply write as
$$F_{X,A} = \hom(F(\hom(-,X)),A).$$
Since $F$ is left adjoint to $U$, we see that
$$F_{X,A} \cong \hom(\hom(-,X),U(A)),$$
where the additive structure on these sets comes from $A$.
Let $G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ be any functor. Then a morphism $G \to F_{A,X}$ is given by natural homomorphisms
$$G(Y) \to \hom(\hom(Y,X),U(A))$$
for $Y \in \mathcal{C}$. These correspond to natural maps
$$\hom(Y,X) \to \hom(G(Y),A).$$
Now we apply the Yoneda Lemma, and see that we are reduced to an element of $\hom(G(X),A)$, proving the claim.
